# A question about generators for an Ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals

Suppose K is an algebrically closed field. Let $J, K, L \subset K[x_1, ... , x_n]$ be a nested sequence of ideals, i.e. $J \subset K \subset L$. Now suppose that both J and L are generated by n polynomials. Does it follow that K is generated by n polynomials.

What I've done is to try and play around with examples of the form $I(X) \subset I(Y)$ for algebraic sets $Y\subset X$. One example (that killed my inital "proof") was
$$\langle xy,zy,xz\rangle\subset \langle y,xz\rangle$$.

I have no intuition if this is true or not. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: "\langle" and "\rangle" for $\langle$ and $\rangle$, not "$<$".

Comment: Note that if $K \ne (0)$, you can take $p(x) \in K$ then let $J = (a_1p(x),a_2p(x),....,a_np(x))$ where the $a_n$ are distinct constants, then $J$ is generated by $n$ polynomials and $J \subseteq K \subseteq L$, so really you are just asking if sub-ideals of an ideal generated by $n$ elements is generated by $n$-elements.

Comment: I’m afraid it’s false, even when all $n$ generators are necessary for $J$ and $L$. Take $J=(x_1^2,\ldots,x_n^2)$, $L=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, $K$ to be the ideal generated by the $x_ix_j$, $1\leq i \leq j$, so that $J \subset K \subset L$, $J \neq K \neq L$.

Comment: @Mindlack looks like an answer to me! Would you care to record this below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s false, even when $n$ generators are necessary for $J$ and $L$.

Indeed, take $L=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, $J=(x_1^2,\ldots,x_n^2)$, $K=L^2$. Then $K$ has $n(n+1)/2$ generators (the $x_ix_j, i \leq j$ and I am pretty sure this can’t be improved – as pointed out in Mohan’s comment), while $L,J$ have $n$ generators (and this can’t be simplified).

Comment: Thank you, that's a great example!

Comment: Not that it is important, but your $n^2$ is not correct, $x_ix_j=x_jx_i$. It is $n(n+1)/2$.